# How can I find out who (what user) commits deleted lines of code for a given Git commit?

Tags: git

In Git version control, I want to find out who (what user) originally commits deleted lines of code for a given commit.

How could I find this?

I want to check this for many Git commits; therefore using a graphical interface is not an option. I am looking for a Git command (or consecutive commands) to automate this process with a Python script.

Comment: The person who deleted the lines in a commit is the same person who made the commit. I don't think that's what you're asking. Could you clarify?

Comment: With a given commit, you could know what line of code deleted or added in a repository. Deleted line of code is belong to another person who originally added to repository with a different commit. I want to find that user. 

I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to find who originally added a line which was just deleted?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: The [mention-bot](https://github.com/facebook/mention-bot) may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to find who originally added a line which was just deleted? For example, in [this commit](https://github.com/evalEmpire/perl5i/commit/4519fb29cef9a9cff1051ead444457735c3fec90) we see the line `=head1 C<import>` deleted. Who wrote that line originally?

```
--- a/lib/perl5i.pm
+++ b/lib/perl5i.pm
@@ -1118,27 +1118,29 @@ Example:
     from CPAN or another repository.  Your library paths are:
         Indented list of paths, 1 per line...

-=head1 C<import>

-This subroutine is called automatically, see L<perlfunc/import>.
+=head1 Turning off features
...
```

The command you want is [`git blame`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame). This will show which commit last modified each line. For our example, `git blame lib/perl5i.pm` would show us who last touched each line of the file.

```
b755dda5 (Michael G. Schwern      2009-04-22 21:29:08 -0700    1) package perl5i;
b755dda5 (Michael G. Schwern      2009-04-22 21:29:08 -0700    2) 
8baa7538 (Michael G. Schwern      2010-01-29 21:34:14 -0800    3) ######################################
a6231688 (Michael G. Schwern      2010-03-14 13:55:50 -0700    4) # The real code is in perl5i::2      #
8baa7538 (Michael G. Schwern      2010-01-29 21:34:14 -0800    5) # Please patch that                  #
8baa7538 (Michael G. Schwern      2010-01-29 21:34:14 -0800    6) ######################################
...
```

That's the commit, the author's name, when the commit happened, and the line.

This isn't necessarily the original author of the line. Even a commit that makes a simple whitespace change will show up. To avoid this, add `-w` to ignore whitespace changes. `git blame -w lib/perl5i.pm`.

But that's for the current commit. You can ask for a blame as of a particular commit, our example is `4519fb29cef` which deleted the line. If we do `git blame -w lib/perl5i.pm 4519fb29cef` the line will already have been deleted so it won't show up in the blame. Instead, do a `git blame` on the previous commit. `git blame -w lib/perl5i.pm 4519fb29cef^`.

```
...
4afdb783 (Lars Dɪᴇᴄᴋᴏᴡ 迪拉斯     2013-03-01 11:16:27 +0100 1121) =head1 C<import>
4afdb783 (Lars Dɪᴇᴄᴋᴏᴡ 迪拉斯     2013-03-01 11:16:27 +0100 1122) 
4afdb783 (Lars Dɪᴇᴄᴋᴏᴡ 迪拉斯     2013-03-01 11:16:27 +0100 1123) This subroutine is called automatically, see L<perlfunc/import>.
...
```

Commit `4afdb783` by `Lars Dɪᴇᴄᴋᴏᴡ 迪拉斯` last touched that line. Since sometimes changes can be trivial, do a `git log -p 4afdb783` to verify it's a significant change. If not, do the same thing again. Run `git blame` on the commit before that one: `git blame -w 4afdb783^`. Continue until you get to a significant change.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive response to my question. I need to automate this process and run it for many git commits. Therefore only git blame can not solve  the problem because it require information about deleted line of codes and change file to target only deleted line of codes in a given commit. 
I have to manually feed this information and I cannot automate this process with a script.

Comment: @MohsenLaali Sure you can. If you want to know who last changed line 45 in foo.txt before commit 4afdb783 you run `git blame -L45,45 foo.txt 4afdb783^`. Add a `-p` to get it in a machine friendly format.

Comment: thank you for comment. 
I still need to put line number and file name.How can I find the deleted line and affected file in a given commit in a machine friendly format? 
I can connect these command with git blame and answer the question.

Comment: @MohsenLaali The output from `git-diff` is in a machine friendly format. It's in [unified diff format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Unified_format) used for patch files.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of git blame: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame

`git blame` accepts a file and annotates each line in the given file with information from the revision which last modified the line. Optionally, start annotating from the given revision.

Or else, you can make use of a graphical tool like `gitk` to see, what does a commit changes and all.

Comment: Git blame works for a given file name and not a given version. 
Would you please send me the exact command? 

With a given version, I want to find out who originally added the deleted line of code for a given commit to a repository.

Comment: If the line `call someUniqueLine` was deleted by `54e872ea` in `filename` then you can git blame for that line in the parent commit with
`git blame filename -L '/^call someUniqueLine/',+1 54e872ea^`

Comment: If you want to see all the commits(history of all commits) on a file and what changes are made to it, you can use `gitk <filename>` if installing gitk is not a problem for you.

Comment: Thank @RaviTezu for comment. I want to run this command for many commits and using a graphical interface is  hard for this propose. I am looking for a git command to mix with my python script to automate this process.

Comment: Thank you @Steve, how can I find the deleted line and file name for a given commit?

Comment: @MohsenLaali I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to find all lines that were deleted by a given commit, and for each one output the original author, not just the user who last modified it? I'm not sure, that's quite a lot, maybe modify your question with the specifics. (Also, that's quite a few steps, some of which might be better as individual questions)